# Git shows no log

Tags: git, github

**Intention:** I tried to synchronize my *local repository* with *remote repository* . 
**Intention Symbolically** : *Local repository* => *Global Repository.*

**Expected** : Synchronize, so that my *global repository* will be exact as same as *local repository*, thats :

1. If there exists **any** files in *local repository* those files **must** be in the *global repository*.
2. If there exists **certain** files in *global repository* and are **not** in the *local repository* those files **must** get deleted.

**What I tried**:

```
 git fetch --prune origin
 git reset --hard origin/master
 git clean -f -d
```

**What it did**: Above snipped of code synchronized global repository with local repository and deleted all my latest work that was in local repository.
**Symbolically:** *Global repository* => *Local repository*

Further : `$git log` **shows only initial commit**. However, I have made various commits.

```
    Xahid@Xealot MINGW32 ~/Desktop/About (master)
    $ git log
    commit 28bdd84cf003789146d4bb42ca479252e8c33d3a (HEAD -> master)
    Author: Username <email@gmail.com>
    Date:   Wed Apr 22 11:55:45 2020 +0530

    Started project
```

Comment: Show the output of `git reflog`

Comment: @SaurabhPBhandari `git reflog` shows all the commits. $ git reflog
28bdd84 (HEAD -> master) HEAD@{0}: checkout: moving from master to master
28bdd84 (HEAD -> master) HEAD@{1}: branch: Reset to @
28bdd84 (HEAD -> master) HEAD@{2}: reset: moving to origin/master
13decb4 HEAD@{3}: commit: Updated website.
28bdd84 (HEAD -> master) HEAD@{4}: commit (initial): First commit

Comment: You can use git reflog to get back to the last commit

Comment: did you try `git reset HEAD~1`? If you want to scrap the uncommitted work, you can go `git checkout .` first. I think `git reset --hard HEAD~1` can do both.

Comment: @VPaul `git reset HEAD~1` shows `fatal: ambiguous argument 'HEAD~1': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.` and `git checkout .` shows `Updated 0 paths from the index`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the reflog output, you should go back to this HEAD state : `HEAD@{3}` which represents the state of the repo before this `git reset --hard origin/master`.

```
git reset --hard HEAD@{3}
```

**Note**: Try this on a copy of your repository. Also note that hard reset will remove all uncommitted changes.

Comment: How can I sync my local repository with global repository?

Comment: @ZahidKhan `git pull` will fetch the changes from global repo and merge it in local repo. But you can do `git fetch` first and see what `git status` says and take a decision to merge based on it

Comment: Will it satisfy my expected criteria I have specified in the question.

Comment: @ZahidKhan From what I understand from the criteria stated above, you basically want your global repository to be exactly as your local repository and that means you need to do a force push but that is usually bad idea especially if your working with other collaborators